# Match button click to new rails controller method inside a form tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've got a `form_tag` and an existing submit_tag that maps to a rails controller method. My `.haml` code is shown below:

```rb
 .form-group
   =form_tag "/set_limits", {id: 'ec2-instance-limit-form'} do |form|
        = submit_tag "Increase Limits", {class: "btn btn-danger"}
```

A snippet of my routes.rb file matching the url `/set_limits` to a method of a rails controller is shown below.

```rb
match '/set_limits', to: 'limits#handle_limit_request', via: [:post]
```

I now added a button on the same page.

```rb
%button.btn.btn-info(id="customer-status" type="button") Customer Status
```

However when I click this button the request still routes to the `handle_limit_request` method. I would like the action of clicking this button to route to a new method via POST, say `limits#check_customer_status`. How do I route the button click to a new controller method while ensuring that the action of clicking the `submit_tag` still routes to `limits#handle_limit_request`?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the action of clicking this button to route to a new
>   method via POST, say `limits#check_customer_status`

In order to do so, use [button_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

```
= button_to "Customer Status", '/check_customer_status', :method => :post, :form_class => "btn.btn-info", id: "customer-status"
```

Note - Position of this button `(Customer Status)` on the page should be outside of `form_tag` scope, as `button_to` internally generates a form also, `form within a form` may not work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I need the value of some of the input fields inside my |form|, how can I see those values inside `/check_customer_status`?

Comment: @VictorCui Sorry I don't get it, form_tag is another form and routes to different URL and button_to is routed to another URL if you need the value before clicking of form or anything like that can be handle by javascript/jquery.

Comment: I would read the form input values when I click the submit_button using javascript/jquery, but I need to make a backend call using the AWS SDK's for ruby when I click the `button_to`. Perhaps I can create an AJAX POST call that in turn passes the form input data to my Rails controller?

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best way may be to handle this in controller itself other then routes or from passing different url to form_for.

```
.form-group
   =form_tag "/set_limits", {id: 'ec2-instance-limit-form'} do |form|
        = submit_tag "Increase Limits", {class: "btn btn-danger", name: "increase_limits"}
        = submit_tag "Customer Status", {class: "btn btn-danger", name: "customer_suport"}
```

Then in limits controller,

```
def handle_limit_request
  if params[:increase_limits]
    # Do stuff for first button submit
  elsif params[:customer_suport]
    your code for method "check_customer_status"
    or 
    render check_customer_status
  end
end
```